# MySQL JOIN or SUBQUERY on SET from current result row

Tags: mysql

I have a table named DEPARTMENTS that has a column named EMPLOYEES which is a SET:

```
department | employees
----------------------
sales      | 100,107
support    | 120,121
```

And another table named EMPLOYEES:

```
employee | active
-----------------
100      | true
107      | false
120      | true
121      | true
```

I'm trying to void looping through the results and making another connection just to determine if the EMPLOYEE is ACTIVE.  Basically, I need another column with the ACTIVE employees, the result something like:

```
department | employees | active
-------------------------------
sales      | 100,107   | 100
```

I tried what I thought was an obvious:

```
SELECT departments.*, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(employee) FROM employees WHERE employee IN(departments.employees) AND active = true) AS active ...
```

Which failed and I don't understand why, because if I do this manually:

```
SELECT departments.*, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(employee) FROM employees WHERE employee IN(100,107) AND active = true) AS active ...
```

Which works.

Any advice appreciated :) Seems like a simple problem but for some reason escaping me ..

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I updated my question with an example result ( thanks :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and aggregate with `group_concat()`.
The function `find_in_set()` can be used to link each emploee to each departmment.

Assuming that the data type of the column `active` in `employees` is `Boolean`:

```
select d.department, d.employees,
       group_concat(e.employee) active
from departments d left join employees e
on find_in_set(e.employee, d.employees) and e.active
group by d.department, d.employees
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aKYU2kb9B2E23dvsDTBEKT/2).

If `active`'s data type is `varchar` change the `ON` clause:

```
and e.active = 'true'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aKYU2kb9B2E23dvsDTBEKT/3).

Results:

```
| department | employees | active  |
| ---------- | --------- | ------- |
| sales      | 100,107   | 100     |
| support    | 120,121   | 120,121 |
```

Comment: Nice! Beers on me mate, thanks for the help, way less complex than where I was heading and learned something to boot :) :) :)